# Set ImageItem in midp form UNFOCUSABLE

Tags: java, forms, java-me, midp, midp-2.0

I have a midp form where I am adding ImageItem's and StringItem's

I want to be able to select the StringItem's only. When I click or scroll in the form I don't want the images to be selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the answer is *no* - MIDP 2 does not provide API to force form items to be unfocusable. If you *badly* need a greater control, consider using canvas instead of form - although in that case you will probably have to write a lot of code for things that are granted in form.

If you're targeting particular phone model(s) you may check device-specific (non-MIDP) API for features like that - though in this case your MIDlet may not work on other devices